# Health check of materialized views with microservice architecture

Tags: database, microservices, soa

In a microservices architecture, each microservice has its own private datastore.
This brings up the challenges to maintain consistency across multiple services and to implement queries that retrieve data from multiple services.
Regarding the queries to retrieve data from multiple services I would like to implement the materialized view pattern in a search microservice for example.
This materialized view would be asynchronously updated by an event driven design.

There are several patterns to achieve atomicity in an event-driven architecture (e.g. using an event table, mining a database transaction log, using event sourcing, etc.). But in my opinion at the end of the day there are always possibilities of unforseen circumstances where the consistency of the materialized view is not completely guaranteed.

Is there a microservices pattern which executes a health check of a materialized view with the respective data in the others microservices?
Especially in a Microsoft .NET Core environment.

Comment: Is "eventual" consistency an option?  Generally that's what you'd expect in an event driven model, and what you'd get between a master source and its materialized view even without the event model. If you truly require ACID with locks, then I'd say it's time to review the current architecture, which tables belong to who, and the granularity of the services themselves.

Comment: Yes. Eventual consistency is totally fine. I just need a pattern or best practice to check once in a while if the materialized view is still (eventual) consistence or if for an unforseen circumstance one or more events didn't get published or subscribed.